# Assignment causing program to behave strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, chess

I'm making a chess app for practice and I have a function called `movePiece` that gets called after a user selects a square to move a piece to. Before I call it I have a line that gets the destination piece's attribute (queen, pawn, etc..) using a dictionary:

```
secondAttr = pieceDict[posStr][0];
```

Strangely, when I comment out this line my `movePiece()` function gets called correctly, but when I leave it in there nothing happens until I click for a third time. I'm super confused why this random line before my function call that has nothing to do with the function itself is causing such behavior.

Here's a jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eqmbk0u1/
 , the pieces png's are stored on my computer so they won't show up, but they're all in their normal starting spots and when you select one it's square turns blue. See what happens when you **comment out line 67** vs it normally.

Comment: What browser? I see no difference using Chrome?

Comment: It's very hard to see it without the pngs, cause we see the blue square, that disappears either way. @csharpfolk found the reason IMHO

Comment: Chromium, in fiddle: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Your `pieceDict` is incomplete. Is this only happening to pieces that are not present in that dictionary?

Comment: When I highlight a piece and try moving it the alert('moving piece') doesn't show up, until I click another piece.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an error in you `else` block, of you `$('square').click()` event.

```
} else {
            $("#"+firstID).removeClass('selected');
            $("#"+firstID).addClass(lastSqrColor);
            destRow = parseInt($(this).attr('row'));
            destCol = parseInt($(this).attr('col'));
            destID = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
            secondAttr = pieceDict[posStr][0];    //<--- Swap
            posStr = positions[destRow][destCol]; //<--- Swap
            movePiece();
            firstTouch = false;

        }
```

When you first click on a square, you save the name of the piece into `posStr`. Then, on your second click, you overwrite that value with an `undefined` value, because there is no piece in `positions[destRow][destCol]`. If you swap the lines 66 and 67, the code will work, because you set the `secondAttr` before overwriting `posStr`.

Comment: Thanks ItsGreg, I think I need to add a value in my dictionary for "N" which is what I have in my nested array keeping track of positions when there are no pieces in that square.

Comment: Or simply save the row and column of the first click, and then use that on your second click.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying. I'm making a canMove() function that will have the pieces' logic to make sure it can move and for that I need to know what piece is on the destination square.

Comment: In your line 66, you are getting the value of `position[destRow][destCol]`. The values of `destRow` and `destCol` are the row and column of currently clicked square, which is the destination square, where the piece should be moved. However, the piece hasn't been moved yes, so that `position[destRow][destCol]` returns `undefined`.

If you were to use `firstRow` and `firstCol` instead of `destRow` and `destCol`, then it will look up the correct position, and get the piece that you're trying to move.

Comment: I already get the piece I'm trying to move in the if statement on line 53-54. I need to get the second attribute in the else statement because I need to know if the destination square is being occupied or not.

Comment: That is true, but you're not understanding how your code works. The line 53-54 are called when you first click a square. When you click on a different square, they are ignored because of `if(!firstTouch)` and the else block is called. Inside that, you change the strPos to an undefined value, because there is no piece on `position[destRow][destCol]`. 

If you simply swap the lines 66 and 67, the code will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101337/discussion-between-itsgreg-and-markscode).

Comment: I added a value to my dictionary of "N":["none"] so now if there's no piece in the positions array which would be marked by "N" the second attribute will just be set to "none" which seems to work.